# Coin cell UV pendant Q2

Tags: led, diodes, light, coin-cell, uv

I am a beginner with LED lights, but would like to use a 5mm 365nm UV LED diode to make a pendant with a small fluorescent crystal.
I would like to create a very simple, very compact circuit with a coin cell (watch battery), and an on/off switch. What would be the easiest way to do this?

I had asked a similar question earlier, but have a brief additional inquiry to make. How would the circuit change if I wanted to use an LED chip instead? Or if I added other diodes for extra brightness?

Comment: You already have an _unresolved_ question on this at [Coin cell to power a 5mm UV LED?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/535426/coin-cell-to-power-a-5mm-uv-led) do not re-post, especially when you existing question remains unresolved.

Comment: I’m sorry? I’ve clicked the solve button now... I thought with the circuit diagram posted it would be closed already...